# Why is that all in the <ul> tags are not showing on my website?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
<?php
    get_header();

  while(have_posts()){
   the_post();
   pageBanner()
?>
<div class="container container--narrow page-section">
```

//If I Enter any text here it shows on my page but all inside in my  tag are not showing on my page.

```
     <ul class="min-list link-list" id="my-notes">
          <?php 
    $userNotes = new WP_Query(array(
             'post_type' => 'note',
             'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'author' => get_current_user_id()
    ));

    while($userNotes->have_posts()) {
        $userNotes->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <input class="note-title-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
            <textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>
        </li>
```

//if I remove the spacing in between my < ?php and "}" I receive an error of unexpected end of file

```
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please share your full code. I need to check and have you seen any error on front end?

Comment: $userNotes = new WP_Query(array(
             'post_type' => 'note',
             'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'author' => get_current_user_id()
    ));
it seems in this particular array has the problem. and insert plain text. it shows on the front end of my website.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing the closing bracket for your while loop.

```
<?php
    get_header();

  while(have_posts()){
   the_post();
   pageBanner()
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php
  get_header();

  while(have_posts()){
    the_post();
    pageBanner();
  }
?>
```

Same goes for this while loop:

```
while($userNotes->have_posts()) {
        $userNotes->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <input class="note-title-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
            <textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>
        </li>
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work, even though having all the closing brackets